# Built in keyboard not working on virtualbox

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run macOS on my windows 10 laptop. But everytime I boot my system it tries to find a startup.nsh file, I know how to create a .nsh file its just that my virtual box is not letting me type at all. I even tried to use the soft "virtual" keyboard but still nothing. Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: Google for hackintosh.

Answer (score 0):

Making a macOS VM on windows is not simple as any other operating systems, there is many tutorials for that like :https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/macos-windows-10-virtual-machine/
This is because apple makes it's software only for it's products and isn't made to be compatible for other devices out of the box.